# owl carousel on localhost wordpress site Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, owl-carousel

I am at a loss, I have tried multiple solutions on other stackoverflow posts about the error but none have worked. I am new to JavaScript and do not work with WordPress often. Any insight is greatly appreciated! Please do not suggest to use the OWL plugin on wordpress.
If there is somewhere else I should put the content of jquer.js (and not have duplicate navigation arrows as mentioned below, please tell me!!)

Things I've already tried:

- putting the jQuery(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({...}); block inside the document.ready block. This gave the same error, and additional error and made the carousel disappear entirely.
- changing the order of the enqueued scripts in functions.php
  (sometimes the error does go away but then I have two sets of navigation arrows?)
- replacing every '$' in jquer.js with jQuery
- adding the contents of jquer.js to functions.php and then using
  add_action in wp_footer
- changing document.ready to window.load
- renaming jquer.js to owl.carousel.js (and  changing all it's references to match)

The error from the browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).owlCarousel is not a function
    <anonymous> http://localhost/stagingsite/wp-content/themes/strawberry/assets/js/jquer.js?ver=5.4.6:1
jquer.js:1:25
```

In my functions.php file:

```
function strawberry_register()
{
    $version_css = wp_get_theme()->get('Version');
    
    wp_enqueue_style('strawberry-style', get_template_directory_uri() . "/style.css", array(), $version_css, 'all');
    wp_enqueue_script('strawberry-owl-carousel', get_template_directory_uri() . "/assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js", array( 'jquery' ), false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('strawberry-jquery-3.4.1', get_template_directory_uri() . "/assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js", array( 'jquery' ), false, true);
    wp_enqueue_style('strawberry-owl-min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/assets/css/owl.carousel.min.css");
    wp_enqueue_style('strawberry-owl-def', get_stylesheet_directory_uri()  . "/assets/css/owl.theme.default.min.css");
    wp_enqueue_script('strawberry-jquer', get_template_directory_uri() . "/assets/js/jquer.js", array( 'jquery' ), false, true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'strawberry_register');
```

jquer.js:

```
jQuery(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  nav: true,
  dots: false,
  autoplay: 5000,
  stagePadding: 0,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  margin: 0,
  responsiveClass: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 2,
    },
    768: {
      items: 2,
    },
    1025: {
      items: 4,
    },
  },
});

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $(".owl-carousel").each(function (index, el) {
    var containerHeight = $(el).height();
    $(el)
      .find("img")
      .each(function (index, img) {
        var w = $(img).prop("naturalWidth");
        var h = $(img).prop("naturalHeight");
        $(img).css({
          width: Math.round((containerHeight * w) / h) + "px",
          height: containerHeight + "px",
        });
      }),
      $(el).owlCarousel({
        autoWidth: true,
      });
  });
});
```

Relevant from front-page.php:

```
  <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/assets/js/jquer.js"></script>
```

Edit*********
Also in my functions.php file, is called with add_action in wp footer:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the HTML generated from WordPress and/or the Network pane in devtools to verify that the styles and scripts are actually being imported?

Comment: Yes, it does show up in the HTML.

Comment: Is jQuery loading before or after Owl's scripts?

Comment: I apologize, I am new to this, how would I verify where it's loading? In functions.php I do call jquery 3.4.1 before my jquer.js

Comment: I think I understand, I just edited my question to include another part of my functions.php so it is loading after in the footer, while the other stuff is in the head

Comment: I just tried moving those edited lines to be in the head above the owl scripts. I checked and they did show up in the html in the right place, but the error still is the same.

Comment: Your jQuery should be in the document footer followed by your Owl scripts. The order in which they're loaded matters. jQuery plugins have to load after jQuery is instantiated, otherwise they can't append themselves to the jQuery prototype.

Comment: Try moving your `jQuery(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({ ... });` block inside your `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { ... });` block (right before `$(".owl-carousel").each(...)`). This way that block won't be executed before the browser has finished parsing the current page and thus should have loaded Owl's script by then.

Comment: Why didn't I catch that

Comment: So I tried cabreachector suggestion and I'm still getting the same error as well as an additional error (jQuery Deferred exception) and the carousel won't show up at all. Any other tips? and to Selfagency, yes it originally/currently loads JQuery in the footer after all the Owl scripts.